# Make JLabel background transparent in a frame with background

Tags: java, swing, graphics, transparency, jlabel

I have a JLabel on my JFrame and a JFrame with a picture background. The problem is although my JLabel is opaque but it still has a grey background which is annoying.
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField username;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JLabel passwordLbl;
    private JLabel usernameLbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gc;

    public MainFrame() {

        username = new JTextField(10);
        password = new JPasswordField(10);
        passwordLbl = new JLabel("Password: ");
        usernameLbl = new JLabel("Username: ");

        usernameLbl.setOpaque(true);
        passwordLbl.setOpaque(true);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(username, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(password, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(usernameLbl, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(passwordLbl, gc);

        setSize(400, 600);
        setLocation(400, 50);

        setUndecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics arg0) {
        Image img = getToolkit().getImage("pics/blue_and_red.jpg");

        arg0.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

        username.repaint();
        password.repaint();
        usernameLbl.setOpaque(true);
        usernameLbl.repaint();
        passwordLbl.repaint();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: um.... make it ***non*** - opaque. Seriously. Or better, don't even set opaque to false since non-opaque is the default.

Comment: It didn't work by default it was non - opaque.

Comment: Because your paint method is all farked up. Yikes.

Comment: Don't load images while painting, rather - load them once during construction of the class. And don't call repaint from within a painting

Comment: Opaque is the __opposite__ of transparent.

Comment: I did that. But nothing changed!

Comment: Again, you're shooting yourself in your foot with your paint method.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I don't have paintComponent in my JFrame so the the only Solution is overriding paint method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it's frustrating how people aren't ready to listen to advice of the wise ;)

Comment: @MouseEvent : I made opaque false but it didn't worked too, wiseman ;).

Comment: Did you read the second paragraph of Hovercraft's answer?

Comment: I read I will do it, and tell you the results.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. Please check at updated code. This is frustrating for both you and for us.

Comment: It was solved thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paint method is completely farked is the reason for your problem. Don't draw your labels in paint, but **do** call `super.paint(g)` in there.

Better still, don't draw in a JFrame's paint method but rather in a JPanel's paintComponent method and call the super's method there.

i.e.,

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField username;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JLabel passwordLbl;
    private JLabel usernameLbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gc;
    private Image img;

    public MainPanel() {
        img = getToolkit().getImage("pics/blue_and_red.jpg");

        username = new JTextField(10);
        password = new JPasswordField(10);
        passwordLbl = new JLabel("Password: ");
        usernameLbl = new JLabel("Username: ");

        // usernameLbl.setOpaque(true);
        // passwordLbl.setOpaque(true);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(username, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(password, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(usernameLbl, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(passwordLbl, gc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }

        // username.repaint();
        // password.repaint();
        // usernameLbl.setOpaque(true);
        // usernameLbl.repaint();
        // passwordLbl.repaint();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
      // create JFrame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

      // add our MainPanel to the JFrame
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
      frame.pack(); // pack it
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true); // show it
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // this is for starting our Swing app on the event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Most important, read the [Painting with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) standard Swing tutorial, as it's all well explained there.

Comment: It's a JFrame and doesn't have paintComponent unfortunately.

Comment: I tried with super.paint(g) it didn't worked.

Comment: @Iman: as I stated, don't draw in the JFrame, that's a very dangerous thing to do. Draw in a JPanel that you display in the JFrame. This is all explained in the Swing painting tutorial.

Comment: @Iman: [start here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: It worked by adding a JPanel to the JFrame and overriding paintComponent method of JPanel with one repaint() to the end of paintComponent.
@Hovercraft: Thank you very much ;)